# Pine script plots nothing

Tags: pine-script

I'm new to code, I practiced something in pinescript, no compile error but also no output
here is my code
//@version=5
indicator("MACDybabu, MACD by kundal",overlay=false, max_bars_back = 500)

```
fast_length   = input (3, "Fast Length" )
slow_length   = input (5, "Slow Length")
signal_length = input (3, "Signal Smoothing")

fastMA = ta.vwap (high, fast_length)
slowMA = ta.vwap (high, slow_length)
mayc = fastMA - slowMA
signal = ta.rma (mayc, signal_length)


plot (mayc, title="mayc", color= color.orange, linewidth = 2)
plot (signal, title="signal", color = color.rgb(44, 175, 83), linewidth=2)
```

I'm practicing to code in pine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, your ta.vwap is not correctly used.
Your code plot 2 zero values.
To correctly use ta.vwap, you should use it as in this code :

```
//@version=5
indicator("Advanced VWAP")
vwapAnchorInput = input.string("Daily", "Anchor", options = ["Daily", "Weekly", "Monthly"])
stdevMultiplierInput = input.float(1.0, "Standard Deviation Multiplier")
anchorTimeframe = switch vwapAnchorInput
    "Daily"   => "1D"
    "Weekly"  => "1W"
    "Monthly" => "1M"
anchor = timeframe.change(anchorTimeframe)
[vwap, upper, lower] = ta.vwap(open, anchor, stdevMultiplierInput)
plot(vwap)
plot(upper, color = color.green)
plot(lower, color = color.green)
```

source from : [https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_ta{dot}vwap](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_ta%7Bdot%7Dvwap)

Answer (score 0):

I corrected the code
//@version=5
indicator("MACDybabu, MACD by kundal",overlay=false, max_bars_back = 500)

```
fast_length   = input (3, "Fast Length" )
slow_length   = input (5, "Slow Length")
signal_length = input (3, "Signal Smoothing")

fastMA = ta.wma (high, fast_length)
slowMA = ta.wma (high, slow_length)
mayc = fastMA - slowMA
signal = ta.rma (mayc, signal_length)


plot (mayc, title="mayc", color= color.orange, linewidth = 2)
plot (signal, title="signal", color = color.rgb(44, 175, 83), linewidth=2)
```